# Using find command more efficiently?

Tags: find

I am very new to bash scripting and would like to know if it is possible to have two find commands running that split the first level of directories in half and have one run as a background process. This was my idea to make the find command more efficient, but I am having trouble because I do not even know if this would be the way to execute it. any other suggestions to write a find script as efficiently as possible is also a plus.

Comment: You could definitely run two or more invocations of `find` across separate sets of directories using various filename globbing patterns to match the search paths for each. How this would look in practice depends on what your directories are called.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you so much for your input, however I do have a problem. I am not sure if this is the correct way to approach the problem, but I might have to run this file-find script on an enormous amount of directories, and so I have been searching for ways to just generally split the number of directories into equal parts and have a separate find function for each one. If I do it your way will I need to know the names of every directory?

Comment: You could run `find [a-m]* ...`, `find [n-z]* ...` etc in parallel, depending on the names and the locale. Cutting this into equally-sized slices will require detailed knowledge about the size of the directories. OTOH parallelization has its limits in disk performance (and HDD will definitively be worse than SSD) so you may want to run some tests first whether you actually get any significant benefit.

Comment: Do you want to use `find` for some particular reason, or do you simply want to find some file(s) according to some search criteria? `locate` is much faster than `find`, and can be used in many cases (to find some file(s) according to some search criteria). See `man locate` or find some tutorial about it via the internet to get started.

Comment: @sudodus I have looked into find but got discouraged after someone pointing out how it must be updated and I just assumed the updating database would be too tedious of a task for it to run every time I execute the script. Will it be any different to the directory splitting and find command mentioned before in terms of speed?

Comment: In my computer updating the database of `locate` with `sudo updatedb` is only 12 seconds for a root partition in an SSD with 43 Gibibyte used and a data partition in an HDD with 1.1 Tibibytes used. This is much faster than searching with `find`. - And you need only update the database when you know that the files you are looking for might be new.

Comment: @sudodus would it be unwise to have sudo updatedb in the script so that it updates before the locate command?

Comment: It depends on how often you run the script compared to how often the files you are looking for are created or updated. You could even have one script for (automatic?) updating of the database and one script that looks for files.

Comment: I still do not understand what you'd like to achieve. ```find``` is fairly effective in locating the files you'd like to find and making various things with that files. Whether other tool would be more effective depends on what kind of files you want to locate and what you'd like to do with these files. Please describe your case in more details and with examples.

Comment: Operations where I/O is the bottleneck (like this) rarely get more efficient by distributing the load to several threads / tasks (but often get slower).